# Why isn't gulp-uglify mangling my variables names?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I have the following task:

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  gulp.src('./src/scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

And the following 2 javascript files, test1.js :

```
var testOneOutput = 'function one';
console.log(testOneOutput);
```

And test2.js

```
var testTwoOutput = 'function two';
console.log(testTwoOutput);
```

And all the directories are setup correctly. Though when I run the task, I have no indication of whether the uglifying work. The concatenation works great though. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your scripts `testOneOutput` and `testTwoOutput` are global variables and by default `gulp-uglify` only mangles local vars.

Put your code in a function and you'll see some mangling.

```
function go() {
  var testOneOutput = 'function one';
  console.log(testOneOutput);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can give `{mangle: {toplevel: true}}` option if you want to mangle your top level functions as well.

```
uglify({mangle: {toplevel: true}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform the `uglify` first. Then `concat` the uglified files.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  gulp.src('./src/scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```